# Can't execute some of the curl commands in the quickstart guide

Tags: daml

I am working through the [Digital Asset quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html).
I am able to run:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/iou
```

And:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/iou/0
```

Without a problem.  However, I am having trouble running:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"issuer":"Alice","owner":"Alice","currency":"AliceCoin","amount":1.0,"observers":[]}' http://localhost:8080/iou
```

And:

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "newOwner":"Bob" }' http://localhost:8080/iou/ID/transfer
```

I get an output of

`<html><body><h2>500 Internal Server Error</h2></body></html>`

Is there a log somewhere that allows me to see what error occured?  How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First I stopped the mvn, navigator and sandbox processes.  Then I re-ran

```
da run damlc -- package daml/Main.daml target/daml/iou
```

Then I restarted sandbox.  and re-entered

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

Now it works fine...